# scrapy runspider: error: Unable to load 'WebHarvestSpider.py': cannot import name 'squeue' from 'scrapy'

Tags: scrapy

I am trying to run a Scrapy spider with this command:

```
scrapy runspider -a main_url=https://www.imperium42.com WebHarvestSpider.py
```

and I get this error:

```
Usage
=====
  scrapy runspider [options] <spider_file>

runspider: error: Unable to load 'WebHarvestSpider.py': cannot import name 'squeue' from 'scrapy' (Usage
=====
  scrapy runspider [options] <spider_file>

runspider: error: Unable to load 'WebHarvestSpider.py': cannot import name 'squeue' from 'scrapy' (/Users/jv/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/scrapy/__init__.py)
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`scrapy.squeue` was [renamed](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/news.html#scrapy-1-0-0-2015-06-19) to `scrapy.squeues` in Scrapy 1.0.

If the error comes from Scrapy itself, try reinstalling the latest version of Scrapy.

If you are importing `scrapy.squeue` in your code, you need to update your code. See the [Scrapy changelog](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/news.html) for a complete history of Scrapy API changes.

Comment: I found the error. Indeed my code was importing squeue instead of squeues. Thanks!